# Java HttpURLConnection invoke remote server and returned 500 status

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-500

I want to invoke remote server using HttpURLConnection, here is my function:

```
public String invokeAwvsServer(String api, String param, String method){
    System.out.println(api+param);
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    OutputStreamWriter out = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(api);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod(method); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Auth", apiKey);
        connection.connect();

        if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"); 
            out.append(param);
            out.flush();
        }
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            res.append(line);
        }
        return res.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(reader != null){
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(connection != null){
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        if(out != null){
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return "error"; 

}
```

I use this function in its own class and works well, but if I call it in other class ,the remote server return 500 status code and JVM throws exception like:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:...
```

What`s the reason?Thanks a lot:)

Comment: How should we help? Which parameters are you working with?

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace and caller class/methods, and possibly the output in each case

Comment: fine,I find it was because that I use spring @value for api-key but inject failure. So how to delete this question?LOL...